# CSS background image works for regular page, but not for SharePoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm able to add a full-page background image that stretches to fit and doesn't repeat using the following in my custom HTML web page's CSS file:

```
body { 
    background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried doing this in SP 2013 website, but the BG image flickers for a second, then seems to be overridden by a master page blank white background color...

```
body {  
    background: url(http://khsp.cloudapp.net/SiteAssets/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;  
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

To override SP2013's white body background, I added !important, which now doesn't render anything but the white background:

```
background: url(http://khsp.cloudapp.net/SiteAssets/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed !important;
```

I tried moving important to the front, and now it fits the whole page, but is tiled/repeating:

```
background: url(http://khsp.cloudapp.net/SiteAssets/bg.jpg)  !important; no-repeat center center fixed;
```

[image]

How do I get it to fit the whole background in SP 2013 without repeating/tiling? I don't mind if it's stretched.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try separating each style like  this

```
background-image:url('paper.gif') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
..
..
```

Comment: Explain why this works. Be descriptive. Point out what is that OP was missing and/or erring in and then suggest a fix/solution.

Comment: yeah user can you please explain why you need to separate them out?

Comment: you have "!important; no-repeat"  so that no-repeat is not applied. so separating each item gives you better control and visually you can see what is going on .  Also if you

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this:

```
background: url(http://khsp.cloudapp.net/SiteAssets/bg.jpg)  !important; no-repeat center center fixed;
```

is bad because of the ; after the !important (the CSS will stop at that point, which is why it repeats).